# Showing a rational polynomial is non injective

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be a prime number greater than $11$, further let $x<y<z<2p$ be positive integers coprime to $p$, such that $x+y+z=3p$.

Is it possible to show that $f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{xy+xz+yz-2p^2}{xyz}$ is non-injective?

Computationally, I checked this is true for all primes between $11$ and $5000$ and integers between $70$ and $5000$. As $p$ further grows, the number of elements in the image of $f$ that have multiple preimages grows at the rate of $0.2p$.

It's possible to restate this problem in many different forms, e.g., let $\lambda$ be a rational number then using the substitution of $z=3p-x-y$ in $f(x,y,z)=\lambda$ gives a family of elliptic curves. However, I couldn't get it to go anywhere that elliptic curves would help solve.

Does anybody know of this problem or a possible method to solve it?

Comment: I note that the question is equivalent to asking whether there are nontrivial solutions to $$\big(xy+x(3p-x-y)+y(3p-x-y)-2p^2\big)\big(XY(3p-X-Y)\big)=\big(XY+X(3p-X-Y)+Y(3p-X-Y)-2p^2\big)\big(xy(3p-x-y)\big)$$ for $x,y,X,Y$ in certain long intervals. Could exponential sums help?

Comment: Injectivity of a function makes sense when you specify a domain of definition, and typically for a rational function you have many natural choices for the domain of definition. Would you clarify?

Comment: @YCor the domain is described (triples of distinct positive integers less than $2p$, not equal to $p$ and which sum up to $3p$), is not it?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov, yes, that is the domain as I implied it, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is this really about primes? Do you also get non-injectivity for (sufficiently large) composite $p$?

Comment: Indeed, you introduce elements of the domain as one would introduce parameters. Anyway, I understand the question now.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, yes you do get non-injectivity for non primes above 70, in fact most numbers less than 70 are also non-injective, but I don't have my exceptions list to hand right now. But you are correct, it's not really a statement about primes, but is written as such as I need it in the prime case.